# How to run a webpack project without webpack-dev-server?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I'm trying to host my project on GitHub pages by creating a /doc file and putting my html,css,js there.

Here's my project:
https://github.com/mattfrancis888/the_movie_db

The only way to run the project with the css/JS/webpack functioning is with webpack-dev-server downloaded, and then I would run 'npm run develop'.

Any guidance in how I should approach this dilemma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `npm run build` or `yarn build`
This should create a `dist` folder in the directory containing the website. You can deploy the dist folder with GitHub pages

Comment: Wow!! amazing! thank you!!!!!!! lastly, do I drag the whole dist folder to my /doc folder/ or should I just grab the html/css/js files individually?

Comment: You can name the dist folder doc, push it to github, then follow the instructions here: https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site